# What is this formula for mean called and where can I find the derivation

Tags: statistics

$\overline{x}= \frac{\sum{x-c}}{n}+ c$ I'm solving a question that requires this formula and I have done it but I dont understand what the C stands for here

Comment: $c$ is a constant - any number,

Comment: The point being $\sum \limits_1^n (x_i-c) = \left(\sum \limits_1^n x_i\right)- \left(\sum \limits_1^n c\right)= \left(\sum \limits_1^n x_i\right)-nc$

Comment: What is it called though, where can I read about it

Comment: @Fillerepisodesnet there's really nothing to read about. It's just another way to write the mean.

Answer (score 2):

Normally we define the mean by $$\bar{x} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}}{n}.$$  Now, if we wanted to, we could add and subtract by any number $c$ in each term of the sum, to get
\begin{align}\bar{x} &= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_{i} - c + c)}{n}\\ 
&= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_{i}-c) + \sum_{i=1}^{n}c}{n}\\
&= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_{i}-c) + cn}{n}\\
&= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-c)}{n} + c.
\end{align}